# Get conn assigns in channel for Phoenix Framework

Tags: phoenix-framework

I need to get some info from my conn.assigns in my channel. For example:

```
def handle_in("save", params, socket) do
    values = Poison.decode!(params)

    current_user = conn.assigns.current_user
    changeset =
      current_user
      |> build_assoc(:posts)
      |> Post.changeset(values)

    case Repo.insert(changeset) do
      {:ok, _} ->
        {:reply, :ok, socket}
      {:error, reason} ->
        {:reply, {:error, %{:msg => reason}}, socket}
    end
  end
```

But conn obviously isn't available here. How should I go about getting the assigns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The socket has an [assigns](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Socket.html#assign/3) that mirrors assigns on a conn.

If you want to get the user, you will need to use the [Phoenix.Token.sign/4](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Token.html#sign/4) function and pass the value when connecting on the socket.

Something like this in your template:

```
<%= tag :meta, name: "channel_token", content: Phoenix.Token.sign(@conn, "user", @current_user.id) %>
```

And this in your JS:

```
const token = document.querySelector('meta[name=channel_token]').getAttribute('content');
const socket = new Socket('/socket', {params: {token: token}});
```

You can then verify the token in your socket like so (taken from [the docs](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Token.html)):

```
defmodule MyApp.UserSocket do
  use Phoenix.Socket

  def connect(%{"token" => token}, socket) do
    # Max age of 2 weeks (1209600 seconds)
    case Phoenix.Token.verify(socket, "user", token, max_age: 1209600) do
      {:ok, user_id} ->
        socket = assign(socket, :user, Repo.get!(User, user_id))
        {:ok, socket}
      {:error, _} ->
        :error
    end
  end
end
```